# Unexpected system app battery usages

Tags: battery-life, system-apps

Today, I have noticed that, an application named `kworker/u:4` using phone's battery. I haven't seen this app before on battery usage section. Also, I have noticed `kswapd0` application using battery, last week. Are they normal operations?

I am using unrooted Xiaomi phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is completely normal (although on Android you would expect it to be combined with the "System" usage).  See [Kworker, what is it and why is it hogging so much CPU?](https://askubuntu.com/q/33640/8530)

> "kworker" is a placeholder process for kernel worker threads, which perform most of the actual processing for the kernel, especially in cases where there are interrupts, timers, I/O, etc. These typically correspond to the vast majority of any allocated "system" time to running processes.

Similarly, `kswapd` is responsible for managing some kernel memory swapping; you may have seen this because your were running low on memory at some point.